# Which Sitecore Experience Accelerator version should be used with Sitecore 8.2 Update 2?

Tags: sxa

My requirement is to use Sitecore Experience Accelerator in conjunction with a Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 site. However, none of the Sitecore Experience Accelerator packages specify compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 - they all state that Update-1 or Update-3 is required. Which version should I use?

- SXA 1.0.0 states compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 initial release
- SXA 1.1 states compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 initial release
- SXA 1.2 states compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 Update-1
- SXA 1.3 states compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 Update-3
- SXA 1.3.1 states compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 Update-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compatibility is normally a minimal version. So in your case that would mean SXA 1.2.

But I would really recommend you to upgrade your Sitecore solution to update-3 first (minor upgrade) so you can use SXA 1.3(.1). It has some major benefits (e.g. bootstrap) that will make your SXA experience a lot better.

Also note that if you have used a "dynamic placeholder" solution in your existing site, you might run into issues when installing SXA on top of it - take a backup ;)